# Mi foreach me salta un error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Estoy haciendo una gestion de acceso con un Roles, pero cuando hago el foreach para guardar el id rol me salta el error 'La instrucción foreach no puede funcionar en variables de tipo "Rol" porque "rol" no contiene ninguna definición de extensión o instancia pública para "GetEnumerator"'

Este es mi Controllador para hacer el login:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(Usuarios _usuario)
    {
        Da_Logic _da_usuario = new Da_Logic();
        var usuario = _da_usuario.EncontrarUsuarios(_usuario.user, _usuario.pass);
        if (usuario != null)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, usuario.Usuario),
                new Claim("Usuario", usuario.Usuario),
            };

            foreach (string rol in usuario.Rol)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, rol));
            }

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();

        }
    }
```

Esta es la logica para encontrar al usuario:

```
public Usuarios EncontrarUsuarios(string usuario, string password)
    {
        Usuarios obj = new Usuarios();
        var cn = new Conexion();
        //Conect BD
        using (var conexion = new SqlConnection(cn.getcadenaSQL()))
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Usuario = @user AND Password = @password";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", user);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", pass);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            conexion.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    obj = new Usuarios()
                    {
                        Id_Usuario = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id_Usuario"].ToString()),
                        Usuario = dr["Usuario"].ToString(),
                        Password = dr["Password"].ToString(),
                        Id_Rol = (Rol)dr["Id_Rol"],
                    };
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Este es el modelo Rol

```
    public enum Rol
{
    Administrador = 1,
    Empleado = 2,
}
```

y este es el modelo de del Usuario

```
    public class Usuarios
{
    public int Id_Usuario { get; set; }
    public string user { get; set; }
    public string pass{ get; set; }
    public Rol Id_Rol { get; set; }

}
```

Ya he intentado cambiando la logica del foreach pero me sigue saliendo el error. Es el unico error que me marca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usuario tiene un solo rol, por eso no puedes recorrerlo. Es un elemento no una lista de elemento.

En sencillo, tu foreach sobra, debes cambiar esto

```
foreach (string rol in usuario.Rol)
{
   claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, rol));
}
```

Por esto

```
 claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, usuario.Rol.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que el atributo de rol del usuario solo pude tener asignado un rol al no ser lista te saca el error aunque puede ser confuso no enum no es una  lista que esté hecha para recorrerse para que se pueda recorrer, por tanto, no puedes sacar "roles" o string.
Si quieres recorrer Todos los tipos de los roles puedes hacer:

```
     foreach (Rol str in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Rol)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
        }
```

El resultado seria:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De la forma que lo tienes listo solo admite un rol assignado la classe usuarios por tanto si tiene que tener mas de un rol se tendria que usar una lista de roles o array y despues recorrer l'array